# Understanding functioning of read() and lseek() in C

Tags: c, linux

When we use system call open() and then perform I/O operations (especially read() and lseek()), Do the kernel buffer gets updated if we change the file when program is still running? if not, then how to forcefully synchronize live updating file to kernel buffer.

Here is an example:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <sys/types.h>
    #include <sys/stat.h>
    #include <fcntl.h>
    int main()
    {
            int fd=0;
            char ch='\0';
            fd=open("test.dat",O_RDONLY);
            while(1)
            {
                    while(read(fd,&ch,1)!=0)
                    {
                            printf("%c",ch);
                    }
                    printf("\n");
                    lseek(fd,0,SEEK_SET);
                    sleep(5);
            }
            close(fd);
            return 0;
    }
```

Now, I have some data in "test.dat" (say: '3  3 34'). I opened a this file and read it to end and then again seek it to start. Meanwhile, in some editor I opened this "test.dat" file and updated its contents and saved them. Since read() and lseek() are system calls, they shall correspond to changes in updated file if kernel/OS buffer regularly syncs with file in Hard disk. But that is not the case. The changes in file are not reflected from read(), instead it continues to print the initial content. For writing, if have solutions like sync(), fsync() etc. But for reading do we have some such functions?

(Note: one trivial solution to this problem is close() and again open() file descriptor which works perfectly but I want to know and understand some alternative without closing file descriptor)

Comment: You will need both apps to open the file in share enabled mode.  You can do this in your program see the options to `open`.  You probably can not force a 3rd party app to change it's open mode.

Comment: Be careful, [`read`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) returns  `-1` on error, and `-1 != 0` so your loop will become an infinite loop if there's an error. Oh, and you really should check the result of the [`open`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) call as well.

Comment: As for your problem, there are programs that continuously read from file. [`tail`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tail.1.html) with the `-f` option is one such program. Perhaps you can check the source of that program to see how it works?

Comment: Your editor may be moving your original file to a backup, and creating a new file (where the edits are going).  You could easily double check that by using the stat command, and see if the inode is changing on you after editing the file.  If you don't want to pursue all of that, just use the echo command to append to your file, and see if that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some editors make a copy of the file they edit, and finally they move it into the original filename (probably renaming the original to something else), so the file you are reading can be different actually from the one the editor has edited.  This depends on which editor you use to modify the file and is a complex task as you can have several links to the file, so it is expected this operation is not done by the editor.  Ensure you are modifying the original file.  Something useful is to have a different contents file and do (instead of editing the file)

```
$ your_program your_file.txt &
$ cat modified_version.txt > your_file.txt
```

and see what happens.

You have not exposed what editor you use to edit the file.

Comment: Thanks all of you to clarifying this, I did 'ls -ilrta' after saving changes to the file from editor (vim) while my program still executing. I saw this file ".nfs0000<inode_number_in_hex>00*" (temporary file created by editor). Its inode number matched with the file before executing the program. The new file saved by editor was given new inode number.

Comment: That's somewhat weird, as if you have a multilinked file, you loss the rest of the links in favour of the old file and break the link this link was using with the new one.  I think old `vi` overwrote the file to allow the filesystem to conserve the links untouched.

Comment: Instead of vim editor if I modify the file using echo command or another C program, then inode number for file being modified remains same thus the running program detects it